# How to rotate a posted picture

Tags: support, android-app, user-interface, images

I'm using the Android client. I've posted a picture which I would like to rotate (say, clockwise 90 degrees). How can I accomplish this without editing my original picture and reuploading?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, nor do I expect that it is a very common scenario.

Comment: Twp bad, afding a coulple of "rotate" controls could have been simple?

Comment: It's not about simple or not, @Jack - it's about how needed the feature is. And editing pictures isn't really the focus of Stack Exchange. In the rare cases it's needed, the dupe's answers got some good tips.

Comment: Well, if you're on your mobile (eg. Samsung Galaxy SIII), it's easy to look at the picture in the Gallery app, see that the picture is straight, and then upload it just to find it sideways. So, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not possible. Once a picture is uploaded to stack.imgur.com, it cannot be changed at all.